# Restart a generated field?

Tags: custom-object, auto-number

My question is quiet simple:

I have a custom object which his key field is auto-generate. It has this format: **{YYYY}{0000}**.

So it will be something like this:
20150150, 20150151, ... , 20150199

1th January 2016 when i will create a new item, how will it be?

20160200 or 20160001.

If it is 20160200...
How can i get that 20160001?

Thanks all!

Comment: very nice @martin; but that is 'manual' solution. Is not any way to do an authomated process?

Comment: As far as I know this still has to be done manually.